# Squid + OpenVPN : 403 Forbidden

Tags: openvpn, squid

I need to have a proxy server for an already configured and working OpenVPN server.

So I install Squid 5.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.

To test, I changed the following line in the `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file and restarted the `squid.service`:

```
http_access deny all
```

to

```
http_access allow all
```

and then configured the client (OpenVPN Gui):

[image]

But it's not connecting and the error is:

```
Mon Nov 14 17:14:34 2022 HTTP proxy returned: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'
```

I set the proxy for my browser, **and it worked fine**.

So either Squid is not somehow compatible with OpenVPN, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Could you elaborate on network setup? Describe elements such as browser, Squid, OpenVPN client and OpenVPN server with connections between them. Without this it is hard to guess the topology you use.

Comment: I believe network topology and setup is not relevant here. It's a Squid + OpenVPN installed on DigitalOcean. The browser gets the proxy setting from system so any browser will work the same. The client as I've mentioned is OpenVPN GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I am from China, this is because your squid proxy has not been configured properly, squid rejects ports other than 443https by default, so you have to release these ports other than 443

Comment: Hi, welcome to Server Fault! Can you provide any instructions or guidance on how to configure Squid to allow ports other than 443?

Comment: Which country are you in, can I use the established agent?

Comment: Which country are you in, can I use the established agent?